# Add spanish spell check android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to add a custom (Spanish) dictionary to Android Studio. How can I do that?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can download the Spanish (or any other language) ASCII dictionary from http://www.winedt.org/dictASCII.html and then add it to Android Studio:

1. Go to `File` -> `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Spelling` -> `Dictionaries`
2. Click `+`
3. Select path to your dictionaries folder (inside you must have plain text word lists with `.dic` extension)

Comment: This answer is outdated and I couldn't figure out how to add the Spanish spell checker. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Update, based on previous answer and answering comment to it. Just tested it.

Download dictionary from https://www.winedt.org/dict.html
Extract .dic file
Android Studio -> File -> Settings -> Spelling -> + on Custom dictionaries -> select extracted .dic file
Restart Android Studio