# Disable spellchecker on android studio

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

Good morning, I found quite annoying the studio android spellchecker because I develop in Spanish.
How can I turn it off or change the language?
Many Thanks

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797515/add-spanish-spell-check-android-studio).

Comment: Thanks, I had not found this question

Comment: Settings->Project Settings->Inspections->Spell checking